# How to detect PDF printing mode?

Tags: hyperref, pdf

This is the code (this just an example, my real case is bigger, I have two commands `\foo` and `\print` and I need the former to call the latter with one optional argument):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\print[2][bar]{#2}
\newcommand\foo{\print{world}}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello \foo!}
\end{document}
```

It gives me the following warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\print' on input line 6.
```

What's wrong and how can I fix this? In my real case the decision what to print is made by `\print`, so I can't use `\texorpdfstring` inside `\foo`.

This is my real situation. First, there is `\anon` command [inside `acmart.cls`](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/blob/primary/acmart.dtx#L6018-L6023):

```
\newcommand{\anon}[2][ANONYMIZED]{%
  \if@ACM@anonymous%
    {\color{ACMOrange}#1}%
  \else%
    #2%
  \fi}
```

Then, I have my own `\eolang` command [inside `eolang.sty`](https://github.com/objectionary/eolang.sty/blob/master/eolang.dtx#L1357-L1363):

```
\newcommand\eolang{%
  \ifdefined\anon%
    \anon[XYZ]{{\sffamily EO}}%
  \else%
    {\sffamily EO}%
  \fi%
}
```

Finally, I do this:

```
\documentclass[anonymous]{acmart}
\usepackage{eolang}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello \eolang!}
\end{document}
```

And I get the warning.

Comment: `\newcommand\bolder[1]{{\texorpdfstring{\bfseries\color{red}}{} #1}}`  (do you really want an additional space??)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated the question, please take a look

Comment: `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\print{O{bar}m}{#2}`. But it really depends on your real command and what you actually want in the bookmarks.

Comment: I really hate when people changes questions and invalidates the already given answers. Please, make a ***real*** example of what you want to do or it will always be a chase.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry for the confusion. I updated the questions. Now you know all the details.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this problem is that you want to determine **the "string" that `\anon`  eventually prints when it's executed**, which is **extremely difficult to impossible to solve in general case**. Just hard code `XYZ` and use `\texorpdfstring` then.

Comment: (so you get `\texorpdfstring{\anon[XYZ]{{\sffamily EO}}}{XYZ}`)

Comment: (unless you don't care about the text in the bookmark, in that case just disable the feature in hyperref)

Comment: remark, I think fundamentally the issue here is that you're not (yet) very good at TeX programming that even if you're given the solution to the reduced problem it would be difficult for you to adapt to the real problem, and/or your reduction hides the real problem because you don't know where the real problem lies (no insult intended.)

Comment: @user202729 I'm extremely far away from being a good TeX programmer, but I'm a pretty good StackExchange user :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the definition of `\anon` (in a fully compatible way).

```
\documentclass[anonymous]{acmart}

%\usepackage{eolang}
% just the relevant macro from eolang.sty
\makeatletter
\newcommand\eolang{%
  \ifdefined\anon
    \anon[XYZ]{\textsf{EO}}%
  \else
    \textsf{EO}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
% end of excerpt from eolang.sty

% Fix \anon to be expandable
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\ACM@orange}{m}{\textcolor{ACMOrange}{#1}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\ACM@orange\@firstofone}
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\anon}{O{ANONYMIZED}m}{%
  \if@ACM@anonymous
    \ACM@orange{#1}%
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Hello \eolang!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Removing the `anonymous` option gives

[image]

Comment: motivated by the comments posted under the question, I updated the question, please take a look. Many thanks for your details answer, it's very helpful!

Comment: @yegor256 See my comment on your question. Your examples are often too minimized to get a sensible answer. The one in the current form of the question is a prominent case. You ***don't*** want to do that thing, do you?